# Can't get RSS reader

Tags: javascript, rss

I'm new to the programming world and I have to create an RSS feed of the news section of my web.

(HTML files)

```
<div id="categories" onload="cargarRSS()">

</div>
```

(JavaScript files)

```
function cargarRSS(){
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.20minutos.es/rss/tecnologia/");
    news/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=economia&c=yahoo_news&eo=UTF-8;
    feed.load(function(resultado) {
        if (!resultado.error) {
            var capa = document.getElementById("categories");
            for (var i = 0; i < resultado.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var noticia = resultado.feed.entries[i];
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(noticia.title));
                capa.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

But is necessary  connect to the database? How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

Google Feed API has been deprecated: https://developers.google.com/feed/

Try this alternative example, you can get your feeds working with very little work: https://rss2json.com/google-feed-api-alternative